# Is there a Newtonsoft equivalent to the [XMLText] property using in xml serialization?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

EDIT: I realized it might be imported for context, I'm building this JSON for human readability (I don't see there ever been a business need to parse it back into something meaningful later) which is why I need to keep its formatting as simple as possible

So I have an object I want to serialize to JSON. The serialization is complex, and I've created a helper property to handle that. The helper property successfully returns an object every time that matches that way I want it to be serialized. Unfortunately, the serialization engine still shows the helper functions name, instead of just treating its output as a representation of my objects state.

I'm looking to reach the output below

```
{
  "A" : <The output of the helper property>,
  "B" : <The output of the helper property>
}
```

But I actually get

```
{
  "A" : {
    "HelperProperty": <The output of the helper property>
  },
  "B" : {
    "HelperProperty": <The output of the helper property>
  }
}
```

I know in XML formatting there is the [XMLText] attribute that I would apply to the "HelperProperty" property to do this. Is there a similar property in the Newtonsoft landscape? Alternatively, does another Json formatter support this type of operation?

---

MVCE of what I have now

The object that I am serializing to JSON

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class SerializationExample
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public object HelperProperty => (Object)A ?? (Object)B ?? (Object)C ?? "no property specified";

    public int? A;
    public string B;
    public Dictionary<String, int> C;
}
```

Instantiations of that object and serialization thereof

```
var a = new SerializationExample() { A = 5 };
var b = new SerializationExample() { B = "five" };
var c = new SerializationExample() { C = new Dictionary<string, int>() { {"number" , 5 } } };

        
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\users\sidney\desktop\output.json", 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, SerializationExample>() {
        {"a",a },{"b",b },{"c",c } }, Formatting.Indented));
```

How it serializes

```
{
  "a": {
    "HelperProperty": 5
  },
  "b": {
    "HelperProperty": "five"
  },
  "c": {
    "HelperProperty": {
      "number": 5
    }
  }
}
```

How I want it to serialize

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": "five",
  "c": {
    "number": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how your class(es) that you are using to serialize are structured?  In other words, what is the code you are using to reach the output now?

Comment: @BrianRogers I have updated with an MVCE of the class, as well as the behavior I am seeing and what I am hoping to achive.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find an exact solution for what I wanted, I was able to find that you were able to control how your json was serialized, courtesy of https://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/.

All I had to do was define a class

```
public class DirectPropertySerializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var name = value as MyClass;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, name.HelperProperty);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then add an attribute to MyClass

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DirectPropertySerializer))]
```

(Note, as stated above, I don't see a reason to Read this JSON back and try and parse it, so I'm just leaving the ReadJson function as not implemented.